# Unsigned integers on with identity of positive values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unsigned

suppose I have a ddl query,

```
Create table tbl1 (
ID int identity(1,1) not null,
field bigint,
);
```

Isn't that essentially wasting half of the storage? since I know my id always starts from 1 and increment by 1

why does this seems like a common practice?
instead of creating the identity as unsigned
:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: I'm not entirely sure exactly what you are asking here.  Unsigned integers as such are not supported on many dbms's including SQL Server so they cannot be used as identity types.  Adding support for unsigned integers has been suggested but based on responses from vendors seems unlikely to get priority.  Technically speaking, half of the "storage" is not wasted, instead half of the integer VALUES are not used.

Comment: @KenClement could you explain the difference between wasted and not used? afaik, that one bit will never change. so that bit is wasted for each row of record you insert.

Comment: In this case "the storage" is 32 bits.  It is NOT the case that 16 of them are unused or "wasted".  Only the sign bit remains the same (0) in all cases.  This works out to 1/32 of the space "wasted".  Half of the states (bit patterns) that the number could be in remain unusable.  But the concept of "state space" (to coin a term) is distinct from "storage space" - related, but different.  You said "storage space" when you were referring to "state space".

Comment: Minor addendum: actually its half plus one since you are starting at 1 and not 0.

Comment: @KenClement valid points. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no data type for unsigned integers in SQL Server.

The IDENTITY values start usually at 1, but you can create your IDENTITY colunms as

```
create table tab(id int identity(-2147483648, 1) )
```

Comment: my bad, recently switched to sql-server, I thought that the identity keyword  was db agnostic.